# Initialize a list of object at spring boot start up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a List of Book objects which needs to be initialized at Spring boot start up. The list of book is constant and due to DB optimization I don't want to store the data in database and call it every time.

Book class is as below:

```
Class Book{
   private String name;
   private String author;
   private int pages;
   private boolean issued;
}

constructors, getters and setters ....
```

Suppose I have 3 books as (book1,author1,100,true),(book2,author2,50,false) and (book3,author3,350,true)

Which is the best way of initializing the list while spring startup. Moreover once the initialization is done which is the best way in which I can return it through a Get endpoint method in controller as

```
@GetMapping(value="/books")
public List<Book> getBooks(){
  ....
  return <List of three books>;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sameekshya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component
public class BookService implements CommandLineRunner {

    private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

    getters();
 
    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
      // add book to the bookList
    }
}
```

Access booklist in controller -

```
@Autowired
private BookService service;

@GetMapping(value="/books")
public List<Book> getBooks(){
  ....
  return service.getBookList();
}
```